# Get image url with BeautifulSoup where src= data:image/gif;base64,

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I am trying to get urls of images in a webpage using Python and BeautifulSoup4

My current code is

```
import requests

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url="https://goibibo.com/hotels/hotels-in-shimla-ct/"

#Headers

headers={
    'User-Agent':"Mozilla/5.0 (x11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebkit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko Chrome 77.0.3865.90 Safari/537.36)"
}

data = requests.get(url,headers=headers).text
soup = BeautifulSoup(data, 'html.parser')

images = soup.find_all('img',src=True)

print('Number of Images: ', len(images))
print('\n')
for image in images:
    if(image.has_attr('src')):
        print(image['src'])
```

When I inspect the image element it has a proper URL (src="https://cdn1.goibibo.com/voy_ing/t_g/812aa1726b8211e7a0a10a4cef95d023.jpg"). However, when I get the src value of the img element using BeautifulSoup4, it returns data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAIAAAAAAAP///yH5BAEAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAIBRAA7

How can I get the image url given in the webpage?

Comment: Could u provide the actual url of the website that u r tryna scrape?

Comment: @Sushil what's *tryna*?

Comment: Tryna means Trying to...Am lazy to type it out fully XD. But yes, I agree with u @baduker. We can't solve such problems without the actual url.

Comment: Updates my question with the actual URL....

Answer (score 3):

This img tag does not contain reference to some image url, it contains image itself in base64 form (see [w3docs](https://www.w3docs.com/snippets/html/how-to-display-base64-images-in-html.html) for example).

To decode it you'll need to get string after `base64,`:

```
string = string.split('base64,')[1]
```

Than decode it to byte array:

```
import base64
decoded = base64.decodebytes(string.encode("ascii"))
```

And that byte array can be written to file:

```
with open('output.gif', 'wb') as f:
    f.write(decoded)
```

Generally it should be a bit more complicated, because you'll need to consider picture format supplied in the beginning of the data URI `data:image/gif;` (it can be png, jpg, svg as well), but that also shouldn't be very complicated.

Comment: But my trouble is that the url indicated in the HTML can not be retrieved. I tried with other parsers in BeautifulSoup, but without results....